# Iteration over the dictionary and extracting values

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, flickr

I have a dictionary (result_dict) as follows.

```
{'11333216@N05': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '1',
   'iconfarm': 3,
   'iconserver': '2214',
   'id': '11333216@N05',
   'ispro': 0,
   'location': {'_content': ''},
   'mbox_sha1sum': {'_content': '8eb2e248cbad94e2b4a5aae75eb653c7e061a90c'},
   'mobileurl': {'_content': 'https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=11327876'},
   'nsid': '11333216@N05',
   'path_alias': 'kishansamarasinghe',
   'photos': {'count': {'_content': 442},
    'firstdate': {'_content': '1193073180'},
    'firstdatetaken': {'_content': '2000-01-01 00:49:17'}},
   'photosurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/kishansamarasinghe/'},
   'profileurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/people/kishansamarasinghe/'},
   'realname': {'_content': 'Kishan Samarasinghe'},
   'timezone': {'label': 'Sri Jayawardenepura',
    'offset': '+06:00',
    'timezone_id': 'Asia/Colombo'},
   'username': {'_content': 'Three Sixty Five Degrees'}},
  'stat': 'ok'},
 '117692977@N08': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '0',
   'iconfarm': 1,
   'iconserver': '404',
   'id': '117692977@N08',
   'ispro': 0,
   'location': {'_content': 'Almere, The Nederlands'},
   'mobileurl': {'_content': 'https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=117600164'},
   'nsid': '117692977@N08',
   'path_alias': 'meijsvo',
   'photos': {'count': {'_content': 3237},
    'firstdate': {'_content': '1392469161'},
    'firstdatetaken': {'_content': '2013-06-23 14:39:30'}},
   'photosurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/meijsvo/'},
   'profileurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/people/meijsvo/'},
   'realname': {'_content': 'Markéta Eijsvogelová'},
   'timezone': {'label': 'Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna',
    'offset': '+01:00',
    'timezone_id': 'Europe/Amsterdam'},
   'username': {'_content': 'meijsvo'}},
  'stat': 'ok'},
 '21539776@N02': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '1',
   'iconfarm': 0,
   'iconserver': '0',
```

This contains more than 150 usernames `(e.g. 11333216@N05)` . I want to extract `'mobileurl'` for each user and create a dataframe containing `username` and `mobileurl` columns. I couldn't find a way to iterate each user and extract his `mobileurl` as indexing is impossible. However, I have extract the mobileurl for one of the users as follows.

```
result_dict['76617062@N08']["person"]["mobileurl"]['_content']

'https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=76524249'
```

Would be grateful if someone can help, as I'm a bit new to python.

Comment: "for user in result_dict.keys()" will iterate over all the users

Comment: you should really post valid json which we could just load directly into the facility. i.e. pandas in your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the dictionarys list of keys which in this case are the usernames, then use each one to access each top level dict and from there dive through all the other layers to find the exact data you need. The mobileurl in your example.

Once you have these 2 variables, add them to your dataframe.

```
# Iterate through list of users
for user in result_dict.keys():

    # use each username to find the mobileurl you need within
    mobileurl = result_dict[user]["person"]["mobileurl"]["_content"]

    # Add the variables 'user' and 'mobileurl' to dataframe as you see fit
```

Comment: @SamC, thanks for your snippet, I have tried it and append it to a dataframe. As stucash suggested it was the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

```
result_dict = {'11333216@N05': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '1',
   'iconfarm': 3,
   'iconserver': '2214',
   'id': '11333216@N05',
   'ispro': 0,
   'location': {'_content': ''},
   'mbox_sha1sum': {'_content': '8eb2e248cbad94e2b4a5aae75eb653c7e061a90c'},
   'mobileurl': {'_content': 'https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=11327876'},
   'nsid': '11333216@N05',
   'path_alias': 'kishansamarasinghe',
   'photos': {'count': {'_content': 442},
    'firstdate': {'_content': '1193073180'},
    'firstdatetaken': {'_content': '2000-01-01 00:49:17'}},
   'photosurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/kishansamarasinghe/'},
   'profileurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/people/kishansamarasinghe/'},
   'realname': {'_content': 'Kishan Samarasinghe'},
   'timezone': {'label': 'Sri Jayawardenepura',
    'offset': '+06:00',
    'timezone_id': 'Asia/Colombo'},
   'username': {'_content': 'Three Sixty Five Degrees'}},
  'stat': 'ok'},
 '117692977@N08': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '0',
   'iconfarm': 1,
   'iconserver': '404',
   'id': '117692977@N08',
   'ispro': 0,
   'location': {'_content': 'Almere, The Nederlands'},
   'mobileurl': {'_content': 'https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=117600164'},
   'nsid': '117692977@N08',
   'path_alias': 'meijsvo',
   'photos': {'count': {'_content': 3237},
    'firstdate': {'_content': '1392469161'},
    'firstdatetaken': {'_content': '2013-06-23 14:39:30'}},
   'photosurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/meijsvo/'},
   'profileurl': {'_content': 'https://www.flickr.com/people/meijsvo/'},
   'realname': {'_content': 'Markéta Eijsvogelová'},
   'timezone': {'label': 'Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna',
    'offset': '+01:00',
    'timezone_id': 'Europe/Amsterdam'},
   'username': {'_content': 'meijsvo'}},
  'stat': 'ok'},
 '21539776@N02': {'person': {'can_buy_pro': 0,
   'description': {'_content': ''},
   'has_stats': '1',
   'iconfarm': 0,
   'iconserver': '0'}
}
}
```

For your use case better use iteritems() of dictionary:

```
for key, value in result_dict.iteritems():
    print value.get("person", {}).get("mobileurl", {}).get("_content")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=117600164
https://m.flickr.com/photostream.gne?id=11327876
```

Comment: sorry I can't see your output I am behind a proxy, but have you successfully loaded his json sample data?

Comment: his json is incorrect you have to remove last ',' and add '}}' in the last of json to work, thanks

Comment: tried it already can't even get that working; even remove the last incomplete user section.

Comment: wait @stucash i will edit my answer to get that json

Comment: for me, I got it working with `j = pd.read_json(json.dumps(invalid_json))`

Comment: @stucash try it

Comment: yep that'll work with `json.dumps()` for me, `pandas` complains in python 2.

Comment: sorry I forget I can also do `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(result_dict), this way we don't really need to care about json format, it's a plain dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also try to do it more of a pandas way instead of pure dictionary iteration. it's not necessarily the fastest but given you are new to python and pandas, I think it's good thing to know that pandas can handle this well.

I am assuming you are using pandas `DataFrame`, not just dictionary. you could easily achieve the same purpose without converting your json to pandas `DataFrame`. i.e. other answers will work even if you are not a pandas `DataFrame`. they are also valid python dictionary syntax.

```
urls = result_dict[result_dict.index=='person'].apply(lambda x: x['mobileurl']['_content'])
```

here we have selected all rows that have the index as `person` and then we tried to `apply` a function (lambda is the anonymous function we'll be using) to each 
`person`. In this case, we are extracting out the urls using the `lambda` function, then pandas converted the result back to a pandas `DataFrame` (or `Series`) for you to use.

normally I would also care about how fast my iteration is.

(following are done in IPython, a nice tool you could use to do many things in python. %%timeit is a magic function provided by IPython for you to calculate
the time your codes could take)

```
%timeit 
urls = result_dict[result_dict.index=='person'].apply(lambda x: x['mobileurl']['_content'])

1000 loops, best of 3: 133 us per loop (us = microsecond, 10e-6)
```

@SamC provided the fast solution here I can let you know. but like i said, you don't need a `DataFrame` to use his solution. it'll also work for plain dictionary.