# extracting components from json dictionary

Tags: python, json, list

I have a json dictionary (`result_dict_tag`) as follows:

```
{'10644906845': {'photo': {'id': '10644906845',
   'tags': {'tag': [{'_content': 'srilanka',
      'author': '34665545@N05',
      'authorname': 'CrishyM',
      'id': '34660205-10644906845-23098',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'sri lanka'},
     {'_content': 'navy',
      'author': '34665545@N05',
      'authorname': 'CrishyM',
      'id': '34660205-10644906845-7137',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'navy'},
     {'_content': 'vessel',
      'author': '34665545@N05',
      'authorname': 'CrishyM',
      'id': '34660205-10644906845-8792',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'vessel'}]}},
  'stat': 'ok'},
      '11778819726': {'photo': {'id': '11778819726',
   'tags': {'tag': [{'_content': 'sri',
      'author': '44455081@N07',
      'authorname': 'Vinchel',
      'id': '44433751-11778819726-12165',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'sri'},
     {'_content': 'lanka',
      'author': '44455081@N07',
      'authorname': 'Vinchel',
      'id': '44433751-11778819726-12166',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'lanka'},
     {'_content': 'mirissa',
      'author': '44455081@N07',
      'authorname': 'Vinchel',
      'id': '44433751-11778819726-1158107',
      'machine_tag': 0,
      'raw': 'mirissa'}]}},
  'stat': 'ok'}}
```

What I want is to extract the 'raw' words from each dictionary (e.g.`result_dict_tag['10644906845']['photo']["tags"]['tag'][0]['raw']`) and and create a dataframe consisting user id and relevant raw words for each user. I feel this need some for loop. I have written one and it only results the 'raw' words related to first user only. I have gone through documentation and various questions similar to this. But couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may find this question helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47651708/iteration-over-the-dictionary-and-extracting-values/47651828#47651828

Answer (score 0):

You can extract these in a single list comprehension

```
raw_words = [mydict[i]['photo']["tags"]['tag'][k]['raw']
             for k in range(len(mydict[i]['photo']["tags"]['tag']))
             for i in mydict]

print(raw_words)
>> ['sri', 'sri lanka', 'lanka', 'navy', 'mirissa', 'vessel']
```

Comment: Thanks, @Varun, I have tried it. But it showed an error as name i is not defined. I can't figure it out as I am a bit new to python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the list comprehension is properly formatted as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly, what you want is a `list` of `dicts` with each `dict` containing an `id` and a `row`.

Add these lines of code below your dict:

```
new_list = result_dict_tag['10644906845']['photo']["tags"]['tag']

new_desired_list = []

for index in range(len(new_list)):

  tempDict = {} 

  for key in new_list[index]:

      if(key=='id'):
          tempDict['id'] = new_list[index][key]

      if(key=='raw'):
          tempDict['row'] = new_list[index][key]

  new_desired_list.append(tempDict)

print(new_desired_list)
```